# AppleScript access Network Folder

Tags: macos, applescript, finder, automator

I'm trying to make a backup of a folder on our network to my Desktop but I'm not sure how to access the folder on the shared network. My code is as follows:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set desktopFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:James:Desktop:App Backups:"
    set todayDate to do shell script "date '+%Y.%m.%d'"
    set newFolderName to "Backup " & todayDate
    set destinationFolder to desktopFolder & newFolderName
    set sourceFolder to "smb://svr01/IT_Department/Design/_team/James/App"

    tell application "Finder"
        make new folder at alias desktopFolder with properties {name:newFolderName}
        copy folder sourceFolder to folder destinationFolder
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Should I be using the smb://... address or the Volumes/.... address, and how should I format it? I'm a complete AppleScript novice, by the way!

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy` only copies AppleScript values, not application-defined objects. Use `duplicate` command.

```
set sourceFolder to ("/Users/test/Desktop/untitled folder" as POSIX file)
set targetFolder to ("/Users/test/Desktop/untitled folder 2" as POSIX file)
tell application "Finder" to duplicate sourceFolder to targetFolder
```

You can use smb://... address.

Comment: Thanks Parag. This works fine for me if duplicating a folder on the local machine but the network drive is still giving me a "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed" error. The line of code for accessing the network drive is as follows: `set sourceFolder to ("smb://svr01/IT_Department/Design/_team/James/App" as POSIX file)`. The drive is already mounted when I run the script so I doubt it's a permissions problem or anything, but then again I don't know much about this! Any ideas?

Comment: Check with /Volumes/App

Comment: mount volume "smb://svr01/IT_Department/Design/_team/James/App"

Comment: `set sourceFolder to ("/Volumes/IT_Department/Design/_team/James/App" as POSIX file)` did the trick, I should have tried that myself, thanks  a lot Parag!