# Copy mounted folders to local folder

Tags: applescript, mount, finder

We have a samba share from where I'd like to copy folders with an applescript. This is what I already have (the mounting works):

```
mount volume "smb://samba.com/e_18_data11$"
delay 3

set sourcefolder to ("smb://samba.com/e_18_data11$/e_18_data11$/folder1/folder2" as POSIX file)
set localfolder to ("/Users/username/Dropbox/Test" as POSIX file)

tell application "Finder" to duplicate sourcefolder to localfolder
```

This gives me still this error:

```
the routine can not edit objects of this class." number -10010
```

I tried and combined many solutions already on SO, e.g. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251249/applescript-access-network-folder)

– OS X 10.9

Comment: ==> drag the actual sourcefolder from Finder into your AppleScript. It should paste the path into the script. Use that path for sourcefolder. I think that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the `sourcefolder` specification that is wrong.
I think you can just use the volume name instead of "smb://".

```
set sourcefolder to ("/Volumes/7samba.com/e_18_data11$/e_18_data11$/folder1/folder2" as POSIX file)
```

(if the mounted volume is named "7samba.com")

---

Tip: drag the actual `sourcefolder` from `Finder` into your `AppleScript`. It should paste the path into the script. Use that path for `sourcefolder`.

---

More:

The Error your getting is:

```
Mac OS error -10010 (telBadHTypeErr): bad hook type specified
```

I tested it (with two local folders) to see if the script would work. It did work and duplicated the folder.

You can (or should anyway) wrap critical code into a try block, like this:

```
    try

        duplicate sourcefolder to localfolder

    on error the error_message number the error_number
        display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    end try
```

This way you can check and react to errors.

**Addition:**

May be you can check for existence like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set aBoolean1 to get (exists sourcefolder)
    set aBoolean2 to get (exists localfolder)
end tell

log aBoolean1
log aBoolean2
```

Both bool's must be YES

Comment: Also, look up the "duplicate" command from Finder's Scripting Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. I still get the error 
`Finder got an error: Handler can't handle objects of this class. (-10010)`

Comment: I think Finder sees the folders as files, thus the wrong objects?

Comment: …what path got "pasted in" when you dragged the folder on the mounted volume you want to duplicate from the Finder into an AppleScript Document. Did you use that path? More: Finder knows many items and I assume it would duplicate if possible and referenced properly.

Comment: This was it: the Volume is called `/Volumes/e_18_data11$/` and not `/Volumes/7samba.com/e_18_data11$/` ;-) but thanks!!